# Can any one provide example related to polars as_struct().apply()

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I try to add array column to the existing data-frame.  input is something like this

|  1  |  3  |
|  2  |  4  |

and output is

|  1  |  3  |  [?, ?, ?, ?]  |
|  2  |  4  |  [?, ?, ?, ?] |

value of the array will be populated by some custom function.

I try to implement something like this.

```
let df = df![
  "a" => [1, 2],
  "b" => [3, 4]
]?;
        
let lf: LazyFrame = df.lazy().select(
  as_struct(&[col("a"), col("b")]).apply(
    somefn,
    GetOutput::from_type(DataType::List(Box::new(DataType::Float32))),
));
```

I don't know how to implement this `somefn`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of writing a custom function for the apply function in the User Guide, here: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/user-defined-functions/

Ignore the fact that the title implies it's just for Python, there are Rust examples too.

From that page:

```
let out = df
    .lazy()
    .select([
        // pack to struct to get access to multiple fields in a custom `apply/map`
        as_struct(vec![col("keys"), col("values")])
            // we will compute the len(a) + b
            .apply(
                |s| {
                    // downcast to struct
                    let ca = s.struct_()?;

                    // get the fields as Series
                    let s_a = &ca.fields()[0];
                    let s_b = &ca.fields()[1];

                    // downcast the `Series` to their known type
                    let ca_a = s_a.utf8()?;
                    let ca_b = s_b.i32()?;

                    // iterate both `ChunkedArrays`
                    let out: Int32Chunked = ca_a
                        .into_iter()
                        .zip(ca_b)
                        .map(|(opt_a, opt_b)| match (opt_a, opt_b) {
                            (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(a.len() as i32 + b),
                            _ => None,
                        })
                        .collect();

                    Ok(Some(out.into_series()))
                },
                GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Int32),
            )
            .alias("solution_apply"),
        (col("keys").str().count_matches(lit("."), true) + col("values"))
            .alias("solution_expr"),
    ])
    .collect()?;
println!("{}", out);
```